# Zombie page when actual last page got exactly 20 items

Tags: bug, pagination, winter-bash-2015, winterbash-leaderboard

Few minutes ago, I clicked the last page in the [Stack Exchange Network Leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network):

> [image]

Just to be greeted with an empty and sad page:

> [image]

Manually going to the previous page (2186 at the time) showed exactly 20 items in there.

Since that leaderboard is always expanding, I found another site, low traffic which currently have 40 users with hat, and it's indeed reproduced in there: [Tor Leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/tor.stackexchange.com). While it contains only 40 users with hats, it's showing as if there are 3 pages:

> [image]

And clicking page 3 leads to the empty page.